# subtract two columns in a dataframe creating a third in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a ton of columns, they typically follow this pattern:

'on_calculated_3_things_swell',
'on_calculated_3_things_neap',
'on_calculated_3_things_kts',
'on_calculated_3_things_tov',
'on_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc',
'off_calculated_3_things_swell',
'off_calculated_3_things_neap',
'off_calculated_3_things_kts',
'off_calculated_3_things_tov',
'off_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc'

Where they start with either on_ or off_ then have the same endings. I am trying to subtract those that start with on_ from those that start with off_ but have the same suffix after that. It would create a new field starting with dif_ and then the same suffix. This would be a new dataframe and I want to use a loop with a list since the number of variables will grow.

I've tried:

```
calc_vars = ['calculated_3_things_swell',
'calculated_3_things_neap',
'calculated_3_things_kts',
'calculated_3_things_tov']

for i in calc_vars:
     df_diff['dif_' + str(i)] = df.['on_' + str(i)] - df.['off_' + str(i)]
```

but no such luck

Comment: is it a typo the `.` between `df` and `['on_' + str(i)]`? it should be `df['on_' + str(i)]`? same with off

Comment: oh no that was not a typo, that that was in my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dots between you have between `df` and `['on_'...` and `['off_'`.

Also, make sure that they are supported data types. If any of the columns are string types it will not work and you can change them to numeric like this

`df["column_name"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column_name"])`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
 {'string': 'on_calculated_3_things_swell'}, 
 {'string': 'on_calculated_3_things_neap'}, 
 {'string': 'on_calculated_3_things_kts'}, 
 {'string': 'on_calculated_3_things_tov'}, 
 {'string': 'on_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc'}, 
 {'string': 'off_calculated_3_things_swell'}, 
 {'string': 'off_calculated_3_things_neap'}, 
 {'string': 'off_calculated_3_things_kts'}, 
 {'string': 'off_calculated_3_things_tov'}, 
 {'string': 'off_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc'}])
df['data'] = np.random.rand(len(df))
df

                               string      data
0        on_calculated_3_things_swell  0.047960
1         on_calculated_3_things_neap  0.949035
2          on_calculated_3_things_kts  0.441468
3          on_calculated_3_things_tov  0.144224
4   on_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc  0.176003
5       off_calculated_3_things_swell  0.092168
6        off_calculated_3_things_neap  0.300117
7         off_calculated_3_things_kts  0.698156
8         off_calculated_3_things_tov  0.845363
9  off_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc  0.384454
```

---

```
# split and subtract
df[['on', 'suffix']] = df['string'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True)
g = df.groupby('on')
diff_series = g.get_group('on').set_index('suffix')['data'].sub(
    g.get_group('off').set_index('suffix')['data']
)
diff_series

suffix
calculated_3_things_swell        -0.044208
calculated_3_things_neap          0.648918
calculated_3_things_kts          -0.256689
calculated_3_things_tov          -0.701139
calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc   -0.208452
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

---

```
# combine with original df
diff_df = pd.DataFrame({'data': diff_series, 'string': 'dif_' + diff_series.index})
df = pd.concat([df, diff_df], axis=0, join='inner').reset_index(drop=True)
df

                                string      data
0         on_calculated_3_things_swell  0.047960
1          on_calculated_3_things_neap  0.949035
2           on_calculated_3_things_kts  0.441468
3           on_calculated_3_things_tov  0.144224
4    on_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc  0.176003
5        off_calculated_3_things_swell  0.092168
6         off_calculated_3_things_neap  0.300117
7          off_calculated_3_things_kts  0.698156
8          off_calculated_3_things_tov  0.845363
9   off_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc  0.384454
10       dif_calculated_3_things_swell -0.044208
11        dif_calculated_3_things_neap  0.648918
12         dif_calculated_3_things_kts -0.256689
13         dif_calculated_3_things_tov -0.701139
14  dif_calculated_churn_rate_fg2_perc -0.208452
```